# How do I search for the exact phrase?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, lucene

I want to search an exact phrase in `Lucene`.

I am using the below code:

```
public void AddSearchString(string searchString)
{
    MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, ELRNLessonDocument.SearchableFields.ToArray(), new ELRNAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));
    parser.DefaultOperator = QueryParser.Operator.AND;
    parser.PhraseSlop = 0;
    Query.Add(parser.Parse(searchString), Occur.MUST);
}
```

But it doesn't support exact word searches, like: 'Climate Change'. The result must show the exact combination of the text. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use a phrase query](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Terms), by wrapping it in quotes:

```
parser.Parse("\"" + searchString + "\"");
```

Comment: Here the partial word is also working.. for eg: I want to search for "as product". But it shows the result of "was product". It shows because "was" has "as". How can I solve this? Please help

Comment: No, that's coming up because both "was" and "as" are stop words, by default, and stop words are not considered when searching.  They are eliminated because they are generally not meaningful when searching.  If you want them to be considered, you'll need to make the change to your analyzer.  You would really have to go out of your way to make "as" match "was".  At it's simplest, you'd need to use a wildcard query, set lucene to allow leading wildcards, and accept the terrible performance that comes along with it.

Comment: You are saying that, its not take the partial word.. right??

Comment: Right.  Read on what StandardAnalyzer does.

Comment: If you have trouble searching even after adding quotes then make sure you don't have QueryParser.Escape(searchQuery); before your search query. If you do then you have to remove that line to make it work.